# use existing database in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

hey i'm new  to  laravel  Is that possible with Laravel 5.3 to connect to a existing database ? without make  migrations  manually ?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Next question?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  do you have  a  link or something  to show  me  how  to connect  with  the 
 database ?

Comment: migrations are only for creating table structures in database - they are not linked to connetcting

Comment: @NoOorZ24 yes  this is  what i need  i have  created  tables  but  i don't  want  to create  50 tables  again  is  there  any way  to use  them ?

Comment: Just put database config info in your env file and create Models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your project folder there is a file `.env`, in this file set the following DB details:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.1.12
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=*****
```

and run `php artisan config:cache`, your application is connected with the given DB details.

Comment: Sounds great !!